# Apache poi Excel line chart points

Tags: java, excel, apache, charts, apache-poi

I am creating an Excel file with line chart. I've created chart and filled it with data but I cannot create points on my chart. Does anyone know, is there a way I could generate these points(triangles, squares, circles etc.) in a chart using apache poi?

[image]

This is my code for generating current char:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet dataSheet = wb.createSheet("linechart");

        final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 10;
        final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 4;

        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
            row = dataSheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                cell.setCellValue(rowIndex * ((colIndex + 1) + ((int) (Math.random() * 10))));
            }
        }

        Drawing drawing = dataSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 2, 3, NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 15, 20);

        Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
        ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
        legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);

        LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();

        ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

        ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 0, 0));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 1, 1));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys2 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 2, 2));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys3 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 3, 3));

        LineChartSeries series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
        series1.setTitle("one");
        LineChartSeries series2 = data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
        series2.setTitle("two");
        LineChartSeries series3 = data.addSeries(xs, ys3);
        series3.setTitle("three");

        chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

        XSSFChart xssfChart = (XSSFChart) chart;
        CTPlotArea plotArea = xssfChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();
        plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSmooth();
        CTBoolean ctBool = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
        ctBool.setVal(false);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].setSmooth(ctBool);
        for (CTLineSer ser : plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
            ser.setSmooth(ctBool);
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("chart.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution:

```
CTPlotArea plotArea = xssfChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();
CTMarker ctMarker = CTMarker.Factory.newInstance();
ctMarker.setSymbol(CTMarkerStyle.Factory.newInstance());
for (CTLineSer ser : plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
    ser.setMarker(ctMarker);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Following code will give you what exactly you are looking for

```
    CTPlotArea plotArea = xssfChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();
    plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSmooth();
    CTMarker ctMarker = CTMarker.Factory.newInstance();
    ctMarker.setSymbol(CTMarkerStyle.Factory.newInstance());
    CTBoolean ctBool = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
    ctBool.setVal(false);
    plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].setSmooth(ctBool);
    for (CTLineSer ser : plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
        ser.setSmooth(ctBool);
        ser.setMarker(ctMarker);
    }
```