# Apache POI Manage Scatter Chart

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, scatter-plot

I am using the `apache poi` library, version `apache poi 4.1.1`.
I create a scattering chart using the example `ScatterChart.java` of https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/ but there are line instead dot in chart.

Any suggestion?

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: The answer depends on used `apache poi` version and code which creates the scatter chart. Please provide both in your question.

Comment: Hi Axel, i'm using the version 4.1.1 of apache poi.

Comment: Please edit your question and do providing all necessary informations there. And what code is used to create the scatter chart? Please do also providing that code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scatter chart in `Excel` always has lines between the data points.

If you are looking at the example code, there is a method `private static void solidLineSeries` which formats those lines to have colored fill.

What you need is a `private static void setLineNoFill` which sets a not filled line between the data points.

Additional you need set `XDDFScatterChartData.Series` marker style and marker size using [XDDFScatterChartData.Series.setMarkerStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFScatterChartData.Series.html#setMarkerStyle-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.MarkerStyle-) and [XDDFScatterChartData.Series.setMarkerSize](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFScatterChartData.Series.html#setMarkerSize-short-).

Complete Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

/**
 * Illustrates how to create a simple scatter chart.
 */
public class ScatterChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");
            final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 3;
            final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

            // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
                row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                    cell.setCellValue(colIndex * (rowIndex + 1.0));
                }
            }

            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

            XDDFValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            bottomAxis.setTitle("x"); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010765
            XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setTitle("f(x)");
            leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

            XDDFDataSource<Double> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));


            XDDFScatterChartData data = (XDDFScatterChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.SCATTER, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
            XDDFScatterChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFScatterChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
            series1.setTitle("2x", null); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855842
            series1.setSmooth(false); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138

            series1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE);
            series1.setMarkerSize((short)5);
            setLineNoFill(series1);

            XDDFScatterChartData.Series series2 = (XDDFScatterChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
            series2.setTitle("3x", null);

            series2.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE);
            series2.setMarkerSize((short)5);
            setLineNoFill(series2);

            chart.plot(data);

            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-scatter-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void setLineNoFill(XDDFScatterChartData.Series series) {
        XDDFNoFillProperties noFillProperties = new XDDFNoFillProperties();
        XDDFLineProperties lineProperties = new XDDFLineProperties();
        lineProperties.setFillProperties(noFillProperties);
        XDDFShapeProperties shapeProperties = series.getShapeProperties();
        if (shapeProperties == null) shapeProperties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
        shapeProperties.setLineProperties(lineProperties);
        series.setShapeProperties(shapeProperties);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Axel, in my code the setLineNoFill missed. 
Thanks!